# Easy way to individually adjust the justification of text in a table?

Tags: tables

I have a simple table and want to center only the titles of each column, how can I individually center them ?

I tried `\centering{}` but this only works for the first column.

Comment: how about using a `multicolumn`?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{title}`

Comment: `\centering` works the same way in a table as out of it, it works in vertical mode (do `p` columns) but not in horizontal (LR) modeso `\mbox` or table `l` columns.

Comment: @cmhughes I already have the table set out, how do I incorporate `\multicolumn` with the table ? Do I have to change everything ? :\

Comment: just the bit you want to change- see Gonzalo's comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\multicolumn`, as advised in the comments. Here is a baby example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{title~1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{title~2}\\
foofoofoo & barbarbar \\
foofoofoo & barbarbar \\
foofoofoo & barbarbar \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```